# Logarithm problem question

Tags: logarithms

$$a^{bx} = c$$

```
Solve for x
```

$$\log a^{bx} = \log c$$

$$bx \log a = \log c$$

$$x = \frac{\log c}{b \log a}$$

Is this correct?

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I am assuming that $a$ is positive.

Comment: What are the ranges of the parameters and the variable?

Comment: @joriki: Ranges aren't mentioned in the question

Comment: @Andre: thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

No ranges are given. As André noted in a comment, some assumptions are required. If $a$ is assumed to be a positive real number, your calculation is correct.